# Append new values to the same key in a Python dictionary

Tags: python

I am inputting:

```
5
A 3
A 2
A 4
B 13
B 14
```

And I want to put them in the dictionary like this.

```
{A: ['3', '2', '4'] , B['13','14']}
```

But I got this:

```
{'A': ['3', '2', '4'], 'B': ['1', '3', '14']}
```

I tried:

```
N = int(input())
d = dict()

for i in range(N):
    first,second = [j for j in input().split()]
    if first in  d:
        d[first].append(second)
    else:
        d[first] = list(second)
print(d)
```

Comment: See what `list('13')` results in!

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
d[first] = [second]
```

not

```
d[first] = list(second)
```

`list(string)` iterates over `string` and places each individual character as a separate element in the list.

`[string]` creates a list with the entire `string` as an element.

Answer (score 0):

Here after the input it checks whether it is already in the dictionary and if it appends the new value and if it isn't already there then it creates a new list in the dictionary.

```py
N = int(input())
d = dict()
for i in range(N):
    i = input()
    lst = i.split()
    if lst[0] in d:
        d[lst[0]].append(lst[1])
    else:
        d[lst[0]] = [lst[1]]
print(d)
```